# predictionio pio build giving build error

Tags: predictionio

I am trying to build cml project using `pio build`, getting some build
error

I executed in the cml folder, cml/project folder but I am getting same
error

> [WARN] [Console$] This engine project directory contains an auto-generated
> manifest that has been copied/moved from another location.
> [WARN] [Console$] Regenerating the manifest to reflect the updated
> location.     This will dissociate with all previous engine instances.
> [WARN] [Template$] template.json does not exist. Template metadata will
> not     be available. (This is safe to ignore if you are not working on a
> template.)
> [INFO] [Console$] Using command '/home/vagrant/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt' at the > current working directory to build.
> [INFO] [Console$] If the path above is incorrect, this process will
> fail.
> [INFO] [Console$] Uber JAR disabled, but current working directory does not > look like an engine project directory. Please delete
> lib/pio-assembly-0.9.7-aml.jar manually.
> [INFO] [Console$] Going to run: /home/vagrant/PredictionIO/sbt/sbt  package
> assemblyPackageDependency
>
> [ERROR] [Console$] [error] Not a valid command:
> assemblyPackageDependency
> [ERROR] [Console$] [error] Not a valid project ID:
> assemblyPackageDependency
> [ERROR] [Console$] [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
> [ERROR] [Console$] [error] Not a valid key: assemblyPackageDependency
> (similar: sbtDependency)
> [ERROR] [Console$] [error] assemblyPackageDependency
> [ERROR] [Console$] [error]                          ^
> [ERROR] [Console$] Return code of previous step is 1. Aborting.

Please let me know how do I proceed.